# 'lest': How did 'less that' evolve to mean 'for fear that'?

Tags: etymology, old-english, middle-english

> lest, conj.    = [[OED]](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107487?redirectedFrom=lest#eid)      Etymology:  Old English phrase *þý lǽs þe* , lit. ‘whereby less’
>   = Latin quōminus
>    (þý instrumental of the demonstrative and relative pronoun + lǽs [less adj.](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/107464#eid39333196) + þe relative particle). In Middle English the first word of the phrase was dropped,
>   and *les þe* became *les te* in accordance with the general rule that *þ* after *s* changed into *t*.
>
> 1.a. [...] = Latin *nē*, English ***that..not*, *for fear that***.
>
> [[Etymonline]](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=lest&searchmode=none) [Similar to [Wiktionary's entry](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lest#Etymology)]
>   c. 1200, contracted from Middle English phrase ***les te* "less that,"**
>   from Old English phrase *þy læs þe* "whereby less that,"
>   from þy, instrumental case of demonstrative article þæt "that" + læs (see [less](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=less&allowed_in_frame=0)) + [þe](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%BEe#Old_English) "the."
>   The *þy* was dropped and the remaining two words contracted into *leste*.

How should the etymology be interpreted, to understand how  **"less that"**
 evolved and drifted semantically to mean:
OED's definition 1a above (***that..not*, *for fear that***)?
What semantic drifts connect **"less that"**  with ***that..not*, *for fear that***?

Comment: It seems similar to me to the meaning of "less" in "unless."

Comment: @sumelic Will you please enlarge on your comment? How so?

Answer (score 1):

This usage of *lest* is learned and clearly modeled after Latin, as your source itself mentions, specifically (timeo) [ne](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ne#Latin) (Wiktionary).

In fact, *ne* can be an adverb or declarative conjunction (like *that*) of negation, used for instance after verbs of fear to indicate what one fears i.e. hopes not to be. And *less* is a form of negation just like *ne* or *meno* (see https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/meno#Italian ).